# Windows store apps c# - capslock on/off

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, capslock

I have managed to determine if capslock is on or off, so that I can display proper error message. But my code works only, if capslock is off when textbox gets focus. But if it is on, then error message appears when it shouldn't.

```
private Boolean CapsLock = false; //here...how to determine if it is on or off propperly
private void loginCredentials_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    switch (e.Key.GetHashCode())
    {
        //...
        case 20: 
            CapsLock = (CapsLock) ? false : true;
            errorMessage.Text = (CapsLock) ? ((App)(App.Current)).loader.GetString("capslockError") : String.Empty;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: `CapsLock = (CapsLock) ? false : true;` is the same as `CapsLock = !CapsLock;`

Comment: Anyway, can you just use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx ?

Comment: IsKeyLocked is part of System.Windows.Forms. This library is not included for windows store apps :/ am I right?

Comment: Use CoreWindow.GetKeyState() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WinRT method to find the current key status is [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getkeystate), so you can check the key value directly if you need to (similar to the `IsKeyLocked` mentioned in comments).

I'd note that switching on the hashcode of the key pressed seems wrong, you should check the key value itself against the code from the [`VirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) enum (I guess you've noticed that the hash code is just this value, meaning that it works).

If you do need to know immediately when a key such as the caps lock is pressed in general, not just when your text field has focus, you can register a key handler on the application root visual. Normally key presses will be consumed by controls like a text box that handle them, but you can use `AddHandler` with `true` parameter to listen to all key presses including handled ones, something like:

```
Window.Current.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyUpEvent, new KeyEventHandler(...), true);
```

Or alternatively use the `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp` event.

Comment: Don't hide that link to CoreWindow.GetKeyState() so much, it is exactly what he needs.  He has no use for KeyUpEvent.

Comment: Indeed, I figured that out already :) Now it works. Thanks guys

Comment: Good point Hans, I'll admit that I wasn't aware of that method when I started writing the answer, edited.